# CORS with credentials and whitelist of multiple domains

Tags: dns, cors, whitelist

I am trying to enable CORS to allow for a whitelist of multiple domains, uploading images and using GET to retrieve images using res.sendFile.

These all work independently based on my CORS setup but I cannot get them all to work together.

I am using ubuntu, nginx, nodejs.

This is what works for the multiple domain whitelist and uploading:

```
var whitelist = ['http://localhost:8100', 'https://somedomain.com'];
var corsOptions = {
origin: function (origin, callback) {
if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
  callback(null, true)
} else {
  callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

But this fails when using GET to retrieve images using sendFile.

Using GET to retrieve images works when I set up CORS like so:

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:8100'}));
```

or

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'https://somedomain.com'}));
```

But that does not allow for multiple domains.

I have tried adding the following to the corsOptions:

```
methods: 'GET,PUT,POST',
credentials: true,
```

That did not work.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems to be working but I would appreaciate any advice on a better way to do it - if there is any.

```
var whitelist = ['http://localhost:8100', 'https://somedomain.com'];
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: whitelist }));
```

Thanks.